# Is there a good component for showing a text log on screen in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, logging, uitableview

I want to have a screen in my app that shows real-time log information - e.g. a scrolling list of textual strings.  Previously I've seen people just use a textview and append new log entries to the list - it seems this may be not so efficient, especially when the list becomes long. Is there any sample code out there that can efficiently show real-time text log information?   Or does everyone just write their own using a tableview?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableView would be the way to go here, and using the `deque` idea Alex mentioned above, just call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and  `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` as you push/pop log entries onto your deque.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing. You might also use a fixed-width font so you can more easily determine the necessary row height, or you could display one truncated line and use a detail disclosure indicator sort of scheme to display the whole log entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building your own, perhaps you could use a [deque](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/chdatastructures) of `UITextView` instances, adding to the end of the queue and removing from the front, only buffering a constant number of instances.

You could perhaps feed the deque to a `UIView` that contains the text views as subviews, with various offsets set based on how many lines your application is displaying at one time.